# What was happening in Wakanda in the "end credit" scene of Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the "End Credit" scene of [*Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/), we saw Maria Hill and Nick Fury driving in the street and then there was a message on the radio. Nick then asked Maria, "what is it?" Maria answers, "Multiple bogeys over Wakanda, more powerful than New York". After that, they turn into dust by the snap. So that means when they were talking, at the same time Thanos was trying to snatch the Mind Stone, or already did, and was ready to snap.

Now the main point; all those "space-crafts" carrying Thanos' armies landed over Wakanda much earlier. Then what were those "multiple bogeys" Maria referred to? What was going on over there at that moment?

Comment: delay on getting the info?

Comment: the time gap seems to be long. If shield get information after that much delay then how can one expect them to counter any possible invasion?

Comment: it is all the way across the globe... there isn't much they could do anyway

Comment: @Niffler Cool nickname :)

Comment: Your question boils down to why wasnt shield involved in infinity war from beginning when avengers were engaged and shield seems to scratch head only at the last and till then they were BUSY with something else, maybe shawarma

Comment: It's a while since I watched it, but didn't they turn off Wakanda's defences mid way through the fight (including the thing that disguises the whole area as a forest)? So what was happening may have been cloaked until that point, then it was "Hey, suddenly we can see Wakanda! Zoom in the satellites, let's see what they're up to. Ha ha, those crazy guys, they're having some big fight again. Zoom in more, let's try to spot those armoured rhinos we heard so much about. Wait... What the heck are *those* things?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> All those "space-craft"s carrying Thanos armies landed over Wakanda much earlier.

Actually, no...they land about an ***hour*** earlier. The whole "Battle of Wakanda" from seeing the delivery vehicles descending from orbit to the "snap" is only **one hour**.

Now, we don't know the relative times but since Wakanda and NY (I assume) are both in daylight, it's not inconceivable that it's afternoon in Wakanda and morning in NY.

So, Hill/Fury get notified of the "bogeys" at some point (and it should be pointed out that we don't know **who** they are working for) but it's not unlikely that there has been *some* delay between the "bogeys" being noticed by whatever detection systems are in place and two operatives (*thousands of miles away*) from being notified.

Plus it seems (it's hard to tell) that the snap takes some time to propogate across the world/universe so this might also add to the delay.

Comment: If the snap takes even a second to go from Wakanda to NYC, it would take years to go across the universe. On the other hand, Marvel does not seem to care much about astronomical distances.

Answer (score 3):

New York is 7 hours behind Johannesburg, so it's reasonable to say that Wakanda is between 7 and 8 hours ahead of NYC.  The events in Wakanda happened sometime after noon, as it had been daylight for several hours before the attack.  Let's say it was 3PM.  That means it would be roughly 8AM in NYC, and in the Summer it's already light by then.  If you play with the time a little, you can see how both could happen simultaneously.  And, that's assuming Maria Hill was getting the information in real time.  If it was delayed even an hour, now you're talking about a roughly 6 hour time difference, and the amount of daylight matches up even better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to think she was referring to the ships departing from Wakanda. Perhaps the report was not about the arrivals of the said bogeys, but their departure..:

[image]

Roughly 5 minutes before the snap, we can see when Thor attacking the ships departing from Wakanda (and at this point they are "over" Wakanda, and not "in/outside" Wakanda.

So maybe they were referring to this sighting instead.

Answer (score -4):

The problem with that scene is timing. Niffler comment is right because when Thanos snap in Wakanda (somewhere in Africa) during a day Nick Fury turn to dust also during a day. Which in New York would be around 6 hours later (the day).
This create the feeling that in NY and Wakanda it's the same time so what you perceive "earlier landing of spaceships" wasn't "earlier that day". It was during the night and Nick Fury simple slept.
The other explanation is that the snap is slower than commercial airplane.

Comment: Nick Fury doesn't seem the type to sleep through a situation like this. That's a weak answer. I would expect he be alerted as soon as possible.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths the other explanation is that they forgot that time zones exist and it don't have in universe explanation.