# Why did Fury and Hill dissapear so quickly?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I am sure that there is a duplicate of this that I have just not been able to find, but this relates to the post - credit tag of Avengers: Infinity War.

It appears that Fury and Hill have only just received confirmation of the alien attack over Wakanda when everything starts going west and people start disappearing, beginning with the car and chopper crash and quickly escalating to Fury's final moment as he just about manages to get a message to Danvers.

As Thanos arrived in Wakanda via the (former) Tesseract / Space Stone / Gauntlet, I assume the report referred to the huge Q - Ship and the Outrider Dropships that were released but literally seconds later we start to see the results of the snap.

Now I know that any references to the cod - mechanics of how the MCU handles space time are unlikely to have little real basis in actual cosmology or physics, but how is it that people seem to start disappearing before enough time has elapsed for the Wakandan battle to have taken place and Thanos' final arrival on the field? Does the effect of the snap ripple out in every direction of space-time due to the combination of the stones or have I just got my timelines confused?

Comment: what do you mean by so quickly?

Comment: bear with me while I get the time codes from the BD...

Comment: Ok, 2:27:42 - Stark still AWOL, monitoring 'multiple bogeys over Wakanda' 2:27:53 - Car crashes in front of them after driver 'dusted' 2:28:16 - Helicopter Crash, 10 seconds later Hill starts to bite it 2:28:46 - Fury starts to go. 1 min and 4 seconds from 'Multiple Bogeys' to Fury's demise. The battle of Wakanda and the final showdown with Thanos seemed to take a little longer than that...

Comment: Very related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96250/46980

Comment: Good answer by Paulie and definite dupe. but still not particularly satisfying given the lack of context by the film-makers. That seems to be the best I can expect tho cheers!